# Adding row of JOINed to already filtered SELECT results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is returning some particular data:

```
  SELECT sub.*
  FROM (
Select item_id, field_id, attr_val from [CONTRACT_ATTR] where item_id in (select item_id from [CONTRACT_ATTR] where field_id = 326 and attr_val = 'Y')
       ) sub
 WHERE field_id = 234 or field_id = 413
```

[image]

The value A750 is associated with the item_pk on the manufacturer table. I want to bring back the item_name from the MFR table and add it as a row for each associated item_id. So 16 would have 3 rows after for example. And the item_name from MRF will be in the attr_val column.

The closest I have right now is this which is pulling in the item_name but on the wrong row and is removing other fields I need.

```
  SELECT sub.*, m.item_name
  FROM (
Select item_id, field_id, attr_val from [CONTRACT_ATTR] where item_id in (select item_id from [CONTRACT_ATTR] where field_id = 326 and attr_val = 'Y')
       ) sub
JOIN MFR m
ON m.item_pk = sub.attr_val and field_id = 234
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR](
    [ITEM_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FIELD_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ATTR_VAL] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UPD_DTT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UPD_USR] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTRACT_ATTR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ITEM_ID] ASC,
    [FIELD_ID] ASC,
    [ATTR_VAL] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MFR](
    [ITEM_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ITEM_NAME] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ADD_DTT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ADD_USR] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [UPD_DTT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UPD_USR] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ACTIVE_IND] [char](1) NULL,
    [ITEM_PK] [varchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MFR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ITEM_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Comment: Can you please add the table schemas to your question?

Comment: Super quick text tables, copy and paste from SSMS to here: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ and click `Create Table` then copy the output and format as code for your question.

Comment: is `[ITEM_PK]` unique?

Comment: @SqlZim It should be. There have been data issues like this though. Just take the top 1 in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer apply()` to get the manufacturer name, and then optionally use the `max() over()` window function to return it for every `item_id` even when `field_id` is not `234`.

```
select 
    c.item_id
  , c.field_id
  , c.attr_val
  , m.item_name /* includes nulls when c.field_id is not 234 */
  , max(m.item_name) over (partition by c.item_id) as mfr_name
from [CONTRACT_ATTR] c
  outer apply (
    select top 1 i.item_name
    from MFR i
    where i.item_pk = c.attr_val
      and c.field_id = 234
  ) m
where c.item_id in (
  select item_id
  from [CONTRACT_ATTR]
  where field_id = 326 
    and attr_val = 'Y'
 )
```